# How to make my cards remain in the same proportions?

Tags: html, css

I have cards in row, but they do not maintain their proportions, so buttons can pop out of the card, and the card changes width/height. I understand that it's because I'm using fixed width and height together with flex. I just couldn't figure what's the best way to make the cards look "the same" on any screen size using good practices.

What I want is to be able to design the cards on some screen size, and then know that when the screen will change, it will look the same. In this case, I want my cards to look the way they look when running the snippet in full screen (And if needed, break line)

This is the code for my current cards:

```css
#cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 3%;
  margin: 0 auto 10vw auto;
  width: 75%;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem 2rem 3rem 2rem;
  width: 18rem;
  height: 16rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  background-color: #00BFFF;
  border: none;
}

.card .content {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.card .button {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 1em 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Hello, World
        <br />
        From Card #1
      </p>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">Link Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Hello, World
        <br />
        From Card #2
      </p>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">Link Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Hello, World
        <br />
        From Card #3
      </p>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">Link Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Hello, World
        <br />
        From Card #4
      </p>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">Link Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the aspect-ratio property !
This property works like for screen ratio (16:9, 4:3) where the first number is the width and the second one the height.

Just calculate the width-height ratio and replace the height property.

```css
    .card{
        width : 15rem;
        /* height : 18rem; */
        aspect-ratio: 1/1.4; /* Change the second value for your needs ! */
    }
```

With this one little line, your card will keep the same proportions regardless of viewport dimensions.

Comment: I think it would help if you specified which CSS class this code applies to

Comment: You're right ! Edited

Answer (score 0):

@pileup, you can do it by setting `flex-wrap: wrap` style to the `#cards` element. And I changed width of card from 18rem to 10rem, since the correct size in full screen was 10rem.
Please check the snippet.

```css
#cards {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 3%;
    margin: 0 auto 10vw auto;
    width: 75%;
  }

  .card {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 1rem 2rem 3rem 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    width: 10rem;
    height: 16rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border-radius: 2vh;
    background-color: #00bfff;
    border: none;
  }

  .card .content {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  }

  .card .button {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 2vh;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding: 1em 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

```html
<div id="cards">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Hello, World
        <br />
        From Card #1
      </p>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">Link Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Hello, World
        <br />
        From Card #2
      </p>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">Link Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Hello, World
        <br />
        From Card #3
      </p>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">Link Button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Hello, World
        <br />
        From Card #4
      </p>
    </div>
    <a class="button" href="#">Link Button</a>
  </div>
</div>
```